# You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6 [SLACKWARE] ERROR

Tags: software-installation, slackware, steam

I am trying to run steam. I installed the StackBuild from the slackbuild websites, ran ./program and installpkg in su. I try clicking the icon and I receive:
'''
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6
'''

After I click enter it exits. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I want to learn how to fix this slackware linux.

Comment: Are you running 64-bit Slackware and which version, 14.2? If so, check out this page: https://docs.slackware.com/slackware:multilib

Comment: glibc may be needed or I am assuming it has something to do with glibc?

Comment: You are running a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS. That means that you ust have the 32 bits libraries installed ("multilib"). Did you install the 32-bit libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I Had to install and configure the OS to be multilib, install vmware and the required other programs and driver and compile it from scratch. Slackware is a true testament to the past. We have come a long way - be thankful for those who made the modern PC something easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

Install libglvnd-compat32:

```
PACKAGE NAME:  libglvnd-compat32-1.1.1-x86_64-1compat32.txz
PACKAGE LOCATION:  ./slackware64-compat32/x-compat32
PACKAGE SIZE (compressed):  164 K
PACKAGE SIZE (uncompressed):  1130 K
PACKAGE DESCRIPTION:
libglvnd-compat32: libglvnd-compat32 (The GL Vendor-Neutral Dispatch library)
libglvnd-compat32:
libglvnd-compat32: libglvnd-compat32 is a vendor-neutral dispatch layer for arbitrating OpenGL
libglvnd-compat32: API calls between multiple vendors. It allows multiple drivers from
libglvnd-compat32: different vendors to coexist on the same filesystem, and determines
libglvnd-compat32: which vendor to dispatch each API call to at runtime.
libglvnd-compat32:
libglvnd-compat32: Homepage: https://github.com/NVIDIA/libglvnd
libglvnd-compat32:
libglvnd-compat32:
libglvnd-compat32: This package contains 32-bit compatibility binaries.
```